# Order of growth - nested loops, outside loop with doubling index

Tags: for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
int sum=0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i *= 2)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        sum++;
    }
}
```

Is the order of growth for this (n*log(n)/2)? (base 2 log)?

Comment: What do you think it is? Why?

Comment: Neither the factor `1/2`, nor the base of the logarithm are relevant to big-O notation (both are constant factors).

Comment: I will edit the question to explain my reasoning.

Comment: Without big-O, the question needs to first define what operations are considered elementary (i.e. to count as `1` time unit)

Comment: @walnut that would be the statement within the inner loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ***O(n)***.

Indeed the inner loop (the loop with `j` as iterator), loops from `0` to `i`. In total it will thus each time make `i` loops.

The outer loop each time doubles `j`, until it hits `n`. This thus means that we will process the inner loop as follows:

```
1 + 2 + 4 + … + n
```

This is a [*gemetric series* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) and is thus equal to:

```
∑j=0⌊log n⌋ 2j = (1-2⌊log n⌋+1)/(1-2) = 2⌊log n⌋+1-1 ≤ 2n-1
```

So the total number of `sum++` instructions is *2n*, and thus *O(n)*.

Comment: I convinced myself that the order of growth of the outer loop is logarithmic. Is my conclusion correct? I can provide my reasoning to that if needed.

Comment: This also causes the asymptotic to not be exactly `2n`, but to oscillate between `n` and `2n` instead.

Comment: @Al2110: the outer loop will run *O(log n)* times yes, but that does not matter. Since the number of loops in the inner loop, depends on the value of *j*, and the sum of all loops up to *k*, is doubled with the loop of *k*.